# How to check if broadcast variable is valid in Spark 2.0?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Lets say I broadcast a variable from driver as follows:

```
var r = sc.broadcast(s)
```

I am accessing the same at the worker:

```
r.value
```

Sometimes above command `r.value` results in null pointer expection (
    `java.lang.NullPointerException`)

To avoid that I need to know if broadcast is success, so that I can proceed with the value r.value. Can someone help me understand how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

In general this shouldn't happen (and should be reported as a bug) **unless you use streaming with checkpointing**. In this context you should follow the instructions [provided in the documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#checkpointing) (examples copied from there):

```
object WordBlacklist {

  @volatile private var instance: Broadcast[Seq[String]] = null

  def getInstance(sc: SparkContext): Broadcast[Seq[String]] = {
    if (instance == null) {
      synchronized {
        if (instance == null) {
          val wordBlacklist = Seq("a", "b", "c")
          instance = sc.broadcast(wordBlacklist)
        }
      }
    }
    instance
  }
}

...

val blacklist = WordBlacklist.getInstance(rdd.sparkContext)
```

Note that instance is volatile and is initialized in a synchronized block.

Answer (score 0):

You can ride of null pointer exception with usage of one of ways described below:

1.pattern matching

```
val result = r.value match {
        case null => "empty"
        case s => s
    }
```

2.Option

```
  val result = Option(r.value).getOrElse("empty")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use scala's `Try` class

```
import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure}

// Suppose you have broadcasted an Int

val bval = Try(broadcastVar.value) match {
              case Success(v) => v
              cast Failure(e) => 0
           }
```

This will return the original value if the operation was `Success` and 0 if the result was `Failure`.